# Explain delegate output result

Tags: c#, delegates

I'm trying to use delegate numberchanger in C#. However, the produced result I don't understand how they works. Could please explain to me ?

**My codes will be ...**

```
delegate int NumberChanger(int n );
class Program
{
    static int num = 10;
    public static int AddNum(int p)
    {
        num += p;
        return num;
    }
    public static int MultiNum(int q)
    {
        num *= q;
        return num;
    }

    public static int getNum()
    {
        return num;
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //Create delegate instances
        NumberChanger nc1 = new NumberChanger(AddNum);
        NumberChanger nc2 = new NumberChanger(MultiNum);

        //calling the methods using the delegate objects
        nc1(1);
        Console.WriteLine("Value of Num: {0}", getNum());
        nc1(2);
        Console.WriteLine("Value of Num: {0}", getNum());
        Console.ReadKey();

    }
}
```

**Output**

```
  Value of Num: 11
  Value of Num: 13
```

Why second output result produce '13' ?

Comment: `nc1(2)` adds 2 to 11, giving 13. Is that not what you expect?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Problem :** though you created two different functions one for `Addition` another for `Multiplication` , you are calling Addition function `AddNum` function twice by ignoring `MultiNum` function.

So asper your `program` you are getting second output : `13` it is expected result.

**Solution :** if you want to call multiplication function

Replace This:

```
nc1(2);
```

With this:

```
nc2(2);
```

**Complete Code:**

```
delegate int NumberChanger(int n);
class Program
{
    static int num = 10;
    public static int AddNum(int p)
    {
        num += p;
        return num;
    }
    public static int MultiNum(int q)
    {
        num *= q;
        return num;
    }

    public static int getNum()
    {
        return num;
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //Create delegate instances
        NumberChanger nc1 = new NumberChanger(AddNum);
        NumberChanger nc2 = new NumberChanger(MultiNum);

        //calling the methods using the delegate objects
        nc1(1);
        Console.WriteLine("Value of Num: {0}", getNum());
        nc2(2);
        Console.WriteLine("Value of Num: {0}", getNum());
        Console.ReadKey();

    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
Value of Num: 11
Value of Num: 22
```